# URL expiration clarification for uploading file through S3 pre-singed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, upload, pre-signed-url

Lets assume we generate a pre-signed URL to upload a file with an expiration time of 15sec. And we start uploading a large file. Should the file upload be completed within 15sec of the URL generation or it can go beyond that if the file upload start within the 15sec time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upload action should start before the expiry time and there is no known restriction on time taken for completing the uploading after it starts. Since the S3 service evaluates the permissions for uploading the file while starting the upload action, it should not be affected by the time taken for actual uploading of the file.

In your case, considering the file size, if the upload fails for any reason then users wont be able to retry after 15 sec.

Below are more details on this point from "[Uploading using Pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)" doc

> That is, you must start the action before the expiration date and time. If the action consists of multiple steps, such as a multipart upload, all steps must be started before the expiration, otherwise you will receive an error when Amazon S3 attempts to start a step with an expired URL. ```